# How to get user is fan in Facebook pagetab app mobile version?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I create a pagetab application.
I set the mobile site url to be usable with mobile.

In the application I check the signed request to see the user is fan:

```
        if($signed_request['page']['id'] == $myPageId) {
            $is_fan = $signed_request['page']['liked'] ? true : false;
        }
```

But in the mobile version Facebook doesn't post signed request, even then the user is logged in (give permission).

I can ask user_likes permission, so I can check liked pages, but I don't want to use extra permissions..

It is possible to solve this without user_likes perm?

Regards,
F

Comment: Facebook does not allow like gates in general any more – **all** possibilities to do that will be removed soon, so you will not be able to do it in a page tab any more as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

- There is no Page Tab on mobile. Even before v2.1 it was not possible to create a Fangate on mobile (that is, without the user_likes permission).
- Fangates are not allowed anymore according to the Platform Policy of Facebook.
- The "liked" parameter will stop working for old Apps in November and is not available anymore in new Apps.
- The `user_likes` permission will not get approved for Fangating, so you cannot use that possibility either.

Fangates are dead.

Comment: Thanks pal, strict rules..
It's approved to use user_likes to give extra features for fans?

Comment: it depends on the features you want to offer, but even if you get user_likes approved for something else: fangating is not allowed because of the policy changes.